# Will differently coloured rolls of turf become the same colour over time?

Tags: lawn

I recently bought some turf rolls and on finding out I didn't have enough, had to panic lay some further rolls from a different vendor. These extra rolls are a deeper green than the originals laid, so will these blend in colour eventually or will there be a differentiation?

Comment: Are they the same type of grass? If not, what types are they?

Comment: Maybe with a photo (close up) we can better answer. IMHO it should blend, but the type of grass (the species) could also be different. (grasses for shadow zones usually are darker)

Comment: Thanks for the swift responses guys. I honestly have no idea if they are different but certainly look it. I do have an image of the lawn as laid but have been unable to upload it.

Comment: Thank you all - I think I have my answer below sadly! Hopefully the coloration will not look too bad once settled. Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: Probably not.

Turf, or grass or sod is a general term referring to a wide variety of plants. Just like saying vegetables can refer to a wide variety of edibles.

Within the world of grass are certain types of grass such as tall fescue, fine fescues, kentucky bluegrass, perennial rye, st augustine, etc.

Within those types are specific cultivars. There are hundreds, maybe thousands, of different cultivars such as Dakota tall fescue, Taos Tall Fescue, Midnight Kentucky Blue grass, etc.

Different types of grass exhibit different characteristics in terms of growth habits, texture, color. Even within a certain type different cultivars have differences. Some cultivars are genetically different colors and respond to different management differently which can affect their appearance. Some have vastly different colors. Some are dark green and some are a lighter green.

If you want your lawn to have a consistent look you should plant the same mixture of grass throughout. If you're laying sod you should get the same type of sod from the same sod farmer.

It is possible that different sod farmers would have the exact same blend but one would have fertilized it more or it was more recently fertilized but chances are you have two different types of grass that do not exhibit the same characteristics.